# How to condense code of when button is clicked in visual basic 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have tried using various bits of code to condense this but every effort ends up in an error of some sort. Is there any way to condense this code through some sort of loop in visual basics 2010?

Thanks

```
Private Sub btnA3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnA3.Click
    seatNumber = "A3"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnA4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnA4.Click
    seatNumber = "A4"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnA5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnA5.Click
    seatNumber = "A5"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnA6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnA6.Click
    seatNumber = "A6"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnA7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnA7.Click
    seatNumber = "A7"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnA8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnA8.Click
    seatNumber = "A8"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnA9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnA9.Click
    seatNumber = "A9"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnA10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnA10.Click
    seatNumber = "A10"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB1.Click
    seatNumber = "B1"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB2.Click
    seatNumber = "B2"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB3.Click
    btnB3.BackColor = Color.Black
    Unavailable()
    RowB()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB4.Click
    btnB4.BackColor = Color.Black
    Unavailable()
    RowB()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB5.Click
    btnB5.BackColor = Color.Black
    Unavailable()
    RowB()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB6.Click
    btnB6.BackColor = Color.Black
    Unavailable()
    RowB()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB7.Click
    seatNumber = "B7"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB8.Click
    seatNumber = "B8"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB9.Click
    seatNumber = "B9"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnB10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB10.Click
    seatNumber = "B10"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC1.Click
    seatNumber = "C1"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC2.Click
    seatNumber = "C2"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC3.Click
    seatNumber = "C3"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC4.Click
    seatNumber = "C4"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC5.Click
    seatNumber = "C5"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC6.Click
    seatNumber = "C6"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC7.Click
    seatNumber = "C7"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC8.Click
    seatNumber = "C8"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC9.Click
    seatNumber = "C9"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnC10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnC10.Click
    seatNumber = "C10"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD1.Click
    seatNumber = "D1"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD2.Click
    btnD2.BackColor = Color.Black
    Unavailable()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD3.Click
    btnD3.BackColor = Color.Black
    Unavailable()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD4.Click
    seatNumber = "D4"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD5.Click
    seatNumber = "D5"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD6.Click
    seatNumber = "D6"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD7.Click
    seatNumber = "D7"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD8.Click
    seatNumber = "D8"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD9.Click
    seatNumber = "D9"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnD10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD10.Click
    seatNumber = "D10"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE1.Click
    seatNumber = "E1"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE2.Click
    seatNumber = "E2"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE3.Click
    seatNumber = "E3"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE4.Click
    seatNumber = "E4"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE5.Click
    seatNumber = "E5"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE6.Click
    seatNumber = "E6"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE7.Click
    seatNumber = "E7"
    ConfirmSeat()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE8.Click
    btnE8.BackColor = Color.Black
    Unavailable()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE9.Click
    btnE9.BackColor = Color.Black
    Unavailable()
End Sub

Private Sub btnE10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE10.Click
    btnE10.BackColor = Color.Black
    Unavailable()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consolidate all these subroutines into a single subroutine and avoid redundancies, perhaps try this code:

```
Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btnSender As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button),
        strSender As String = btnSender.Name

    seatNumber = Mid(strSender, 4) '2nd argument here cuts off the "btn" portion
                                   'of the Button's name

    ConfirmSeat()          
End Sub
```

Once done with that, go into your designer and select all the buttons for which you want to create an event, go to the Properties pane and check the Events button, and go to the Click event. There, click the dropdown and select the 'btn_Click' event.

Hope this helps! Have a great day!